# Fdisk Ubuntu - How to create logical drives inside an extended partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, fdisk

I have 3 partitions as you can see below, 2 Linux type partitions and 1 Extended partition.

I need to create 3 logical drives (sized 200M, 300M, 400M) inside of partition /dev/sdb3.

When I try to ***fdisk /dev/sdb3*** and then enter command '***n***', I get the following output:

***All space for primary partitions is in use.***

Might be a noobie question, but I would greatly appreciate any insight.
[image: Current Partitions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `fdisk` on the whole disk, not the extended partition:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
```

Use `n` to create a logical partition; `fdisk` should say something along these lines:

```
Command (m for help): n
All space for primary partitions is in use.
Adding logical partition 5
First sector (1437744-3490550, default 1437744):
```

If it asks you what kind of partition to create, ask for a logical partition by entering `l`.